# XDMP-NOEXECUTE: Document is not of executable mimetype

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am trying to run a roxy deployed code using scheduled task in Ml-9. The code runs normally if I just hit the app server associated with the database module where the code resides and gives me the desired result, but if I do it through scheduled job, then it says the following error:

> XDMP-NOEXECUTE: Document is not of executable mimetype.

What am I missing here?

these were the settings for the scheduled task:

```
task enabled true
task path /marklogic.rest.resource/monitoring/assets/resource.xqy 
task root /
task type minutely
task period 5
task database monitoring-modules
task modules monitoring-modules
task user admin
task host localhost
task priority normal
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to schedule a REST extension, but those are library modules, not main modules. You can only schedule main modules.

Comment: Yes, that was precisely the issue, defined the main module and it worked, thanks.

Comment: I'll post that as answer..

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to a REST extension, but REST extensions are library modules, not main modules. The scheduler expects main modules.

HTH!